# Sqlite Insert or update with sum

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table used to log data input / ouput:

```
CREATE TABLE io(iodate DATE, xt INTEGER, rv INTEGER)
```

It aims to store total transmitted data by date.

To update it, I use a bunch of query (mix of pseudo code and SQL):

```
SELECT * FROM io WHERE iodate=<today>
if no result:
   INSERT INTO io(iodate, xt, rv) VALUES (...)
else:
   UPDATE io SET rv+=<new_rv> xt+=<new_xt> WHERE iodate=<today>
```

I believe there is a more convenient way to achieve this. Any ideas ?

Comment: do you have a uniqueness constraint on the `iodate` column?

Comment: Yes I do, iodate is unique. The process fill this table continuous and it run weeks without stop.

Comment: But is there a *constraint* on the column; does SQLite enforce the uniqueness?

Comment: Not yet, but I will set _iodate_ as a primary unique key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the primary key on `iodate` column you can use `INSERT OR REPLACE`, just like @Martijn_Pieters said, but you can do it 2 ways:

**First** is to query current data, as you do already and then "insert or replace":

```
SELECT * FROM io WHERE iodate = ?;
...
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO io VALUES (?, ?, ?);
```

Arguments to insert should already contain sums of current and new values for `xt` and `rv`.

**Second** is is to do everything in one query, although the selecting is done anyway, just it's in the subquery:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO io
                select iodate, xt + ?, rv + ? from (
                       SELECT iodate, xt, rv
                         FROM io
                        WHERE iodate = ?
                        union all
                       select ? as iodate, 0 as xt, 0 as rv
                ) limit 1;
```

The main downside of the second solution is that you have to repeat `iodate` twice, so the arguments should be passed in following order: `<new_xt>, <new_rv>, <iodate>, <iodate>`, although it doesn't affect the performance.

The upside is that it's always a single query, no matter if the row is already in table or not.

Hard to tell which one is faster. You have to measure it by yourself.

You can also think of using SQLite's date and time functions, so you don't have to pass `iodate` everytime by yourself. I suspect that your application will always pass current data for `iodate`, in which case you can use `now()` function for `iodate`, or any other related function, so it fits your date format. See SQLite documentation about available date and time functions.

Comment: The second one is exactly the right solution for my problem.
And you are right _iodate_ argument is always current date. So I use date('now') sqlite function.
Thanks.

Comment: You can use named sql parameters, and then you'd only have to pass in the value for iodate *once*, in a python dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no such shortcut as you want in Python sqlite3. You can check instruction of sqlite3 [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html).

I suggest you write code like this. (The same with you in using pseudo code.)

```
...
def findData():
    SELECT * FROM io WHERE iodate=<today>
def updateData():
    update operation
def insertData():
    insert operation
[updateData() if findData() else insertData()]
...
```

Since update/find/insert are most frequent operations when you deal with a database, pack them in a function will be a good solution.

Comment: There are shortcuts in SQLite using `INSERT OR REPLACE` but only if there is a uniqueness constraint in place.